# Intel 8086 Division. Need AX to be denominator not numerator

Tags: intel, x86-16, dos

Need to divide `CL` by 10. I understand that in division `AX` will always be the numerator, but I need it to be the denominator.
In the code below I attempt to move the value I need as the numerator into `AL` and then put 10 into `CL` and divide.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
            Mov Al, Cl
            Mov Cl, 10 
            Div Cl
```

Comment: "I understand that in division Ax will **always** be the numerator, but I need it to be the denominator." - So what is your question? An impossible mission?

Comment: Lol @KarolyHorvath. Is there a way then to divide a register by 10?

Comment: There is no 8 bit by 8 bit divide. There is 16 bit by 8 [divide](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html). You move _CL_ to _AL_, but you need to zero out _AH_ since it is _AX_ divided by 8 bit register or memory, not _AL_.

Answer (score 2):

> Need to divide Cl by 10

So you'll want the quotient back in the `CL` register then.

- Your corrected solution (10 bytes):

  ```
  mov al, cl
  xor ah, ah     ;Clear high byte because DIV will use the entire AX
  mov cl, 10
  div cl         ;Divides AX by 10, leaves quotient in AL
  mov cl,al
  ```
- Shorter solution (6 bytes):

  ```
  mov al, cl
  aam            ;Divides AL by 10, leaves quotient in AH
  mov cl, ah
  ```

  On [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) the `AAM` instruction exclusively divides by 10.
  On [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) the `AAM` instruction can divide by any byte-sized number.
  So this `AAM` instruction is in effect an 8 bit by 8 bit division!

> Is there a way then to divide a register by 10?

All divisions implicitly use the accumulator (`AL`, `AX`, `DX:AX`). Just copy your register to the accumulator first.

Comment: Clever to suggest the use of `AAM` to divide by 10. I don't think I've seen that trick before. The standard trick for division by a constant is to multiply by the reciprocal, but that still requires a fair number of operations. `AAM` is *no doubt* the most optimal way of doing this on the 8088/8086. I wonder how slow that instruction is on modern processors...

Comment: The multiplicative inverse will of course be faster.

Comment: On the 8086 AAM can also divide by any 8-bit number, it just wasn't documented until much later. The 8086 only supported 1 byte opcodes so the second byte of the AAM instruction was an immediate operand just like it is on every x86 processor since.